# list of string matching with input string

Tags: scala

I am learning scala and I have the following issue:
Given  a list in input

```
val listin = List("Apple,January,10",
"Banana,August,15",
"Strawberry,June,20")
```

and a String `val inputstring="Banana,August"`
I want to find the price in column matching with the string. 
I wrote the following code :

```
case class Fruit(name:String, month:String,price:Int)
val splitString=inputstring.split(",")
val listSplit=listin.map(_.spilt(","))
```

But I don't know how to match the case of equality between the string and a line in the list
The expected result is

```
val output="Banana_August_15"`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to replace the commas with underscores, or what purpose the `case class` serves, but this produces the requested result.

```
listin.filter(_.startsWith(inputstring+","))
      .map(_.replaceAllLiterally(",","_")
//res0: List[String] = List(Banana_August_15)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I am just interested with the first line that matches the input string I guess I should use.first()), may you confirm this please, thanks

Comment: There is no `first()` method. You could use `head` to retrieve the 1st element of the results, but that will throw an exception if the `List` is empty, i.e. no match was found. Using `headOption` is safer that way.

Comment: you can use listin.find to find first matching record. The find will stop searching when first match found